# Windows can't read HDD external Mac

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I have a hdd external Seagate. I am using it in OS X El Capitan. 
But, when I connect it to pc with Windows 7.
Windows can't read it.

I have tried to check from disk management, command prompt, it is not detected.

I've trie to reformat in my mac to be :

- ExFat scheme MBR
- ExFAT scheme GUID
- MS-DOS(FAT32) scheme GUID
- MS-DOS(FAT32) scheme MBR

but, all of this format still unreadable in windows 7.

DO you have any ideas how to make it readable in OS X and Windows ?

Thank you.

Comment: So your `Disk Management` in Windows 7 doesn't see the disk at all? This would be a drivers or physical disk issue, then... what does `Device Manager` say? Has the device installed or got any errors displayed?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is the power requirement. If it's a 2.5 inch disk maybe the PC is not putting out enough power o.n the USB port. (Some drives come with Y cables so you can draw power from USB ports to power them). A Mac disk formatted with Exfat should work fine in a PC.

Comment: Could also be a USB3 driver issue on the Windows 7 machine